IPC-2221 Min. conductor spacing for low voltage?
May I have smaller spacing than B1 ( say as 0.05mm) at the conduction spacing if voltage between conductors is around 5V?
I'm curious that IPC conduct spacing of requirement of 0-15V is 0.05mm, but if below 15V this spacing can be reduced linearly? how to caculate? Thanks
Thanks


Smaller, perhaps; but is IPC-2221 a requirement for the design?

You can have what you want but, whether you will have a reliable design is another matter.

IPC-2221 have conductor min. spacing of conductor : 0.015mm for 15V DC. Want to know smaller spacing if voltage is smaller 15V.

I'm curious that IPC conduct spacing of requirement of 0-15V is 0.05mm, but if below 15V this spacing can be reduced linearly? how to caculate? Thanks

I know nothing about your design and which PCB manufacturing process you're using but I would not recommend this.
A manufacturer with quite an advanced process like Advanced Circuits has a minimum track width and spacing specification of 0.00275" (~0.07mm)

You should also be aware that copper feature spacing is typically larger on internal layers, such as a minimum 0.003" (0.076mm) spacing on the Advanced Circuits process.
I suspect that you will really struggle to find a fabricator who is capable of producing PCBs reliably at such a small scale.

I'm curious that IPC conduct spacing of requirement of 0-15V is 0.05mm, but if below 15V this spacing can be reduced linearly? how to caculate? Thanks!
